# angular2 new line after comma in table cell

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am using *ngFor to dynamically populate a table from a mongoDB. In one of the cells I have an array of strings like string1,string2,string3,string4. How do I display the strings as: 
string1, 
string2, 
string3, 
string4

Here is my code:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let audit of audits ">
        <td>{{ audit.installDate  | date:"medium" }}</td>
        <td>{{ audit.appName }}</td>
        <td>{{ audit.environment }}</td>
        <td>{{ audit.userName }}</td>
        /*This is the line with the string[]
        <td>{{ audit.fqdNs }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In my component.ts I am doing

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
public audits: AuditItem[];

constructor(private _dataService: AuditService) {
}    

ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService
        .getAll()
        .subscribe((data: AuditItem[]) => this.audits = data,
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("getAllItems() complete from init " + this.audits ));
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a nested `ngFor`.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let audit of audits ">
      <td>{{ audit.installDate  | date:"medium" }}</td>
      <td>{{ audit.appName }}</td>
      <td>{{ audit.environment }}</td>
      <td>{{ audit.userName }}</td>
      <td>
        <div *ngFor="let fqdN of audit.fqdNs; let lastItem = last">
          <span>{{fqdN}}</span><span *ngIf="!lastItem">,</span>
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the string with  in map and after that in table use innerHTML property to bind

```
  this._dataService
    .getAll()
    .map(x => Object.assign({}, x, {fqdNs: x.fqdNs.join("</br>")}))
```